# How to execute a command after another is finished on Nao robot (in javascript)

Tags: nao-robot

How to make Nao robot execute functions one after the other? 
This makes everything happen at same time:

```
session.service("ALTextToSpeech").done(function (tts) {
    tts.say("Hello world.");
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred:", error);
});

session.service("ALBehaviorManager").done(function (behavior) {
    behavior.runBehavior("Stand/Emotions/Positive/Winner_1");
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred:", error);
});
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain your functions with "done" (or "then" in qimessaging js v2), something like this:

```
session.service("ALTextToSpeech").done(function (tts) {
    tts.say("Hello world.").done(function() {
        session.service("ALBehaviorManager").done(function (behavior) {
            behavior.runBehavior("Stand/Emotions/Positive/Winner_1");
        })
    });
})
```

See the documentation: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index-1.0.html